# Javascript Delay to change Boolean

Tags: javascript, boolean

I am trying to have it so that after a certain amount of time a boolean that starts as false goes to true the code I have so far is here and I don't know how to set up a timer, could I get some help?

```
var alert1 == false;

if (alert1) {
alert ("Hello!");
} else {
}
```

Comment: The functions are called `setTimeout` and `setInterval`.  https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

Answer (score 1):

Using `setTimeout()` method, where you can provide the time in `milliseconds` after that your code will be executed.

```js
let alert = false;

console.log("Begin..... ", alert);
setTimeout(() => {
  alert = true;
  console.log("after 2 secs: ", alert);
}, 2000);
```

Check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) for more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`setTimeout`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) to add a delay for executing code.

```js
setTimeout(function () {
    alert1 = true;
}, YOUR_DELAY_TIME_IN_MILLISECONDS); // Replace with how much time you want to wait
```

Your code will not work because you check it if `alert1` is true at the beginning of the script running, but a few moments later `alert1` will change to `true`. You do not check if `alert1` is true **after** you actually change it to true.  If you want it to alert something in a few seconds, you do not need a boolean.

```js
setTimeout(function () {
    alert("Hello!")
}, 2000); // Replace with how much time you want to wait in milliseconds (this is 2000 milliseconds, which is 2 seconds)
```

Answer (score 1):

You use [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)

```js
var alert1 = false;
// check alert1 value every second
setInterval(()=>{console.log(alert1)}, 1000);
// change it after 5s
setTimeout(() => {alert1 = true;}, 5000);
```